# Как работает CascadeType.REMOVE?

Tags: sql, hibernate

Есть две таблицы `playlist(id, user, title)` и `playlist_content(id, playlist_id, melody_id)`. Нужно чтобы при удалении записи из playlist удалялись все записи из playlist_content, при этом при удалении в таблице playlist_content с playlist ничего не должно происходить (и не должно появляться ошибок). Сделал это так: поставил в сущности PlaylistContent `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` на поле playlist

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "playlist_id", nullable = false)
private Playlist playlist;
```

Будет ли это корректно работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наоборот, нужно добавить `CascadeType.REMOVE` к таблице `playlist` (сущности `Playlist`):

```
@Entity
public class Playlist implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="user")
    private String user;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private Set<PlaylistContent> playlist_contents;
}
```